# Помощь в написании запроса Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Пытаюсь разобраться в запросах Graph api Facebook. Нашел запрос (в одной из тем):

```
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();                    
String userId = token.getUserId();                   
String path  = "/friends";                   
new GraphRequest(                   
    token,                         
    userId + path,                          
    null,                           
    HttpMethod.GET,                           
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {                              
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            // handle the result
            System.out.println("Response error: " + response.getError());                                  
            System.out.println("Raw: " + response.getRawResponse());
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Запрос возвращает:

```
{"data":[],
 "summary":{
 "total_count":49}
}
```

То есть, количество друзей пользователя. Как можно модифицировать запрос так, что бы выводило хотя б им’я и фамилию друга? Спасибо !!

Comment: Вам самому форматирование кода глаз не режет? Удобно, комфортно читать, если бы вас попросили помочь с таким кодом -- вы бы потратили время на ответ или на приведение кода к человеческому виду?

Comment: И вправду, извините...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный ответ означает, что у токена нет разрешения на получение информации о друзьях. Добавьте user_friends в права для токена. Вы можете проверить работу ваших запросов используя [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: А как это сделать ?

Comment: что это? создать токен? или использовать Graph API Explorer? создайте новый вопрос. так как на текущий вы ответ получили.

Comment: Ну не совсем. Ответ на самом дело заключается в том, что запрос /friends возвращает информацию о тех друзьях, которые установили мое приложение, а так как таких нету вот и ничего не возвращает. Количество друзей при этом, возвращается по умолчанию.

Comment: в ваше вопросе ничего нет про приложение и пр. есть вопрос почему возвращается пустой список. я вам дал ответ.

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо за ответ !